# Variable typecase in SQL using CAST operation

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying use CAST operation in SQL to get signed integers result from a VARCHAR.

But i'm getting the same value as result instead of signed integer value.

For eg:

If the value is 65520, i was looking for the result of -16 by using `CAST( '65520' AS SIGNED INT)` in my select query. But i'm getting the same value 65520 again.

Is there any other way to convert the VARCHAR to SIGNED INT using SQL.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT CAST('65520' AS SIGNED INT);
```

Comment: MySQL's int range is -2147483648 to 2147483647.  Why would you expect casting `65520` to a signed int would be any different than casting to an unsigned int?

Comment: Go through this to find out various Integer types ranges for MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Why do you expect -16?

Comment: @P.Salmon because i was receiving a 16-bit Signed int value as  VARCHAR. So, i'm looking for value between -32768 to 32767

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right. But i'm using a 16 bit signed integer(SMALL INT) as varchar not a 32 bit value.

Comment: @Lingaraj Well, you're still trying to cast to a 16 bit integer, which is large enough that no sign bit stuff would be happening with the value `65520`.

Comment: How did you define `-16` is the same as a `65520` in a VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your question like you are trying to cast an unsigned integer to a signed integer, which would result in mapping that value to some negative value, after the sign bit gets removed for the actual sign of the number.  First, MySQL's integer type range is -2147483648 to 2147483647, so the test value you are using would be too small to see anyway, even it could happen, which it can't.

The `SMALLINT` type does have a unsigned rage of 0 to 65535 and a signed range of -32768 to 32767.  But, it is not possible to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to cast a value to a `SMALLINT`.  The best you could do would be to cast to `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`, but this would use again an integer type.

For educational purposes, I also tried creating a table with a signed `SMALLINT` column, and then I inserted the value `65520` to see what would happen.  The result?  `Out of range value for column 'col' at row 1`.  So, we also can't use this option to get the behavior you want.

### Demo